# How can I filter zero's from a Google Sheets Query Function across two tabs?

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have data across two tabs (May22 and Jun22).

Both have identical headings (A to E).

I can amalgamate the two tabs using:
=QUERY({May22!A:E;Jun22!A:E},"select * where Col3 is not NULL",1)

Col3 (C) contains the Amounts. A lot of which are 0.

How can I modify my query above to filter the zero's from column C inside the query? This will dramatically reduce the size of my amalgamated data.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: "where Col3 is not null and Col3<>0"

Comment: Thanks Matt, worked perfectly! I cannot tell you how many iterations of that i've tried!